# How can I save specific window parameters in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use `(current-window-configuration)` to save the size, layout etc of windows, and `(set-window-configuration ...)` to restore them, so that I can toggle between several window setups. However `(current-window-configuration)` also saves the current point in buffers, and I would like to only save the window sizes and which buffers they hold. I have tried two different ways to make this happen:

According to the function help of current-window-configuration, the variable `window-persistent-parameters` controls whats get saved. So now I only need a list of the available window-parameters. But when I look at this variable it's value is `((clone-of . t))`, and I can't find a list of the available window parameters online.

I also tried looking at the object returned by current-window-configuration. It is a window configuration object, and gets printed as `#<window-configuration>`. Is there a way to get into this object, see whats inside and change stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters for `window-persistent-parameters` may be found in [this manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Parameters.html), though it does not seem to help with your question. A different set of parameters may be found by running `(window-state-get nil)`.

The functions that deal with objects returned by `(current-window-configuration)` are listed [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Configurations.html), but it also mentions:

> Other primitives to look inside of window configurations would make sense, but are not implemented because we did not need them. See the file winner.el for some more operations on windows configurations.

At any rate, all these look like really low level stuff, so you might be better off just using `winner.el` rather than a custom made solution.